# Check if preceding sibiling is a title element

Tags: xpath

I need to see if the closest preceding element in the figure is a title element.  My XML-structure looks like this:

```
<section>
<title>Something</title>
<figure><graphic></graphic></figure>
<figure><graphic></graphic></figure>
<p>Some text</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first preceding sibling and verify it is a title:

```
//figure[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I have edited my example a bit, since i sometimes have two figures in a row, and i only  want to check if i have a figure element directly beneath a title and, in such cases, add content to to that figure, not the second one.

Comment: @user2075124: Works for me. The XPath expression returns the first figure only.

Comment: Well, this isnt the first time Arbortext has screved me. Your xpath works (i had to modify it a bit i Arbortext though).