# check if the second child in the section element is a figure

Tags: xpath

I need to check if the second child in the section element is a figure. My XML-structure looks like this:

```
<section>
<title>Something</title>
<figure><graphic></graphic></figure>
<figure><graphic></graphic></figure>
<p>Some text</p>
</section>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath expression should return all sections whose second child is a figure.

```
//section[child::*[2][self::figure]]
```

Have you tried to understand the reply to [Check if preceding sibiling is a title element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407488/check-if-preceding-sibiling-is-a-title-element) ?

Comment: Yes. I have answeared as well :)